# How to set reactive variable from express server?

Tags: typescript, express, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have a ReactiveVar (from Apollo client) in which I store my current user:

```
// cache.tsx

export const currentUserVar: ReactiveVar<ICurrentUser> = makeVar<ICurrentUser>({
  id: 0,
  email: '',
  user_name: '',
  isLoggedIn: false,
});
```

In my express server I want to set the variable with some data:

```
// apolloServer.tsx

import {currentUserVar} from './cache';

  app.use(
      '/graphql',
      cookieParser(),
      (req, res, next) => {
        try {
          if (req.cookies.id) {
            const currentUser = jwt.verify(req.cookies.id, 'supersecret');
            req.userId = currentUser.id;
            console.log(currentUser);
            setTimeout(() => {
              currentUserVar({id: 1, email: 'asd@asd.com', user_name: 'asdasd', isLoggedIn: true});
            }, 1);
          }
          return next();
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      },
  );
```

The Apollo server does show the current user in the server log:

> {
> id: 732,
> email: 'a@a.com',
> user_name: 'alucardu',
> password: '$2b$04$iRMYnsYhpcoVh7.cdTxVUOFZiP8de6O29p4VDFUz0QFqNLGr/xU9.',
> iat: 1635077667
> }

But when I log the `currentUserVar` in one of my components:

```
// DashboardComponent.tsx

import {currentUserVar} from 'Src/cache';

const DashboardComponent = () => {
  const currentUser = useReactiveVar(currentUserVar);
  console.log(currentUser);
  ...
```

I get:

`{id: 0, email: '', user_name: '', isLoggedIn: false}` instead of the expected: `{id: 1, email: 'asd@asd.com', user_name: 'asdasd', isLoggedIn: true}`

So it seems I can't set the `currentUserVar` from my express server. Any tips?